# How to show MIN value with whole table

Tags: mysql, select, min

I have table like:

```
id col1 col2
1   a    55
2   b    77
```

In result i want to see:

```
id col1 col2 MIN(col2)
1   a    55   55
2   b    77
```

Something like that, or in other case, how i can get one minimum value with whole table.

Comment: I would suggest you to fire two queries (one for results and one for min value) instead of complicating it.

Comment: Slowcoder, thanks. I think ill do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` with a subquery which will select the `min(col2)` value for the entire table:

```
select t1.id, 
  t1.col1, 
  t1.col2, 
  t2.minCol2
from yourtable t1
cross join
(
  select min(col2) minCol2
  from yourtable
) t2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aee1/2).

If you want to expand this to only show the `min(col2)` value on the first row, then you could use user-defined variables:

```
select id,
  col1, 
  col2,
  case when rn = 1 then mincol2 else '' end mincol2
from
(
  select t1.id, 
    t1.col1, 
    t1.col2, 
    t2.minCol2,
    @row:=case when @prev:=t1.id then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
    @prev:=t1.id
  from yourtable t1
  cross join
  (
    select min(col2) minCol2
    from yourtable
  ) t2
  cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) r
  order by t1.id
) d
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aee1/7)

If you had more than one column that you want to compare, then you could *unpivot* the data using a `UNION ALL` query and then select the `min` value for the result:

```
select t1.id, 
  t1.col1, 
  t1.col2, 
  t2.MinCol
from yourtable t1
cross join
(
  select min(col) MinCol
  from
  (
    select col2 col
    from yourtable
    union all
    select col3
    from yourtable
  ) src
) t2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/875d1/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The number of columns is fixed, so you can get the minimum value on all the rows as described by @bluefeet.

You could get it on a smaller number of rows (typically 1) by using the logic:

```
(case when t2.minCol2 = t1.col2 then t2.minCol2 end)
```

But this would put NULLs on the other rows.